# make CC=other_cc in windows

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, mingw

maybe this question is stupid but i really am not able to get a way to fix this i am trying to make a file in Cygwin64 i have all the dependency files installed, but when i make the file it throws me this

```
$ make
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -D OS_WINDOWS_NT -ansi -Wall  -O2 -Wno-long-long -I /usr/include   -c -o main.o main.c
In file included from /usr/include/sys/_pthreadtypes.h:12,
                 from /usr/include/sys/types.h:223,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:61,
                 from main.c:5:
/usr/include/sys/cpuset.h:17:30: error: expected expression before ‘/’ token
   17 | #define __CPU_SETSIZE 1024  // maximum number of logical processors tracked
      |                              ^
/usr/include/sys/cpuset.h:19:25: note: in expansion of macro ‘__CPU_SETSIZE’
   19 | #define __CPU_GROUPMAX (__CPU_SETSIZE / __NCPUBITS)  // maximum group number
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/sys/cpuset.h:26:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘__CPU_GROUPMAX’
   26 |   __cpu_mask __bits[__CPU_GROUPMAX];
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/sys/cpuset.h:19:55: error: expected expression before ‘/’ token
   19 | #define __CPU_GROUPMAX (__CPU_SETSIZE / __NCPUBITS)  // maximum group number
      |                                                       ^
/usr/include/sys/cpuset.h:26:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘__CPU_GROUPMAX’
   26 |   __cpu_mask __bits[__CPU_GROUPMAX];
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/sys/cpuset.h:27:1: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union
   27 | } cpu_set_t;
      | ^
In file included from /usr/include/errno.h:9,
                 from main.c:8:
/usr/include/sys/errno.h:14: warning: "errno" redefined
   14 | #define errno (*__errno())
      |
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10/include/stddef.h:1,
                 from /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:47,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:35,
                 from main.c:5:
/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/stddef.h:19: note: this is the location of the previous definition
   19 | #define errno (*_errno())
      |
make: *** [<builtin>: main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: What exactly are you building, and where does the makefile come from? `-I /usr/include` looks suspicious.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat im sorry man i didnt see your comment before i edited it please post in your suggestions

Comment: this is a tool i found https://github.com/matja/bitcoin-tool heres the link

Comment: extracting public key from hash 160 (rmd) is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: I would just ignore the makefile. `gcc *.c -lcrypto -lssl -O2` worked for me, but I was testing in MSYS2. See if works for you, or try `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` instead of `gcc`.

Comment: im sorry but this is laughable but is it a command or a piece of code that i have to change..?? if so where do i change

Comment: A command for you to run.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you've added the `-ansi` option to your compile line:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -D OS_WINDOWS_NT -ansi ...
```

The `-ansi` option tells the compiler to compile your code as if it were ANSI C 89 standard code.  That version of the standard did not support the `//` single-line comment delimiter: it only supports the traditional `/* ... */` comments.

However the header file you're including clearly expects to be able to use `//` comments.  So you cannot use the `-ansi` flag when you compile with these header files.